# Redirect http traffic to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a node server running on a linux aws lightsail server. I have used `bncert-tool` for an ssl certificate. I also have linked a domain to my instance. Now the problem im having is when I load my site with `http://` I get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` but when I load the site with `https://` the site loads as expected. I know I have to add an http to https redirection to my `bitnami.config` file but the `bncert-tool` automatically does that but I went ahead and checked if [what's mentioned here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws-templates/apps/wordpress/administration/force-https-apache/) is appied properly and everything checks out. Do I have to do anything else to automatically redirect all traffic on http to https? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 so I have to purchase a load balancer just for https redirection?

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 thanks for trying to help but I already mentioned above that I tried the exact link you commented.

Comment: (sorry, am idiot...)

Answer (score 0):

You can create  public certificate for SSL from AWS Certificate Manager. After creation of certificate, you need to create new record as a Cname at the place where you managed your domain. After doing that, you will see, your website will have a SSL connection. More information about [requesting a public certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html).

Comment: my problem is not getting an ssl certificate